# Extracting number from a string that looks like a function call with 1 parameter

Tags: php, regex, string, text-extraction

I would like to extract a number from a string. The string looks something like this:

```
"visaObs(31124228);"
```

Here is my shot at it. It doesn't seem to get any matches:

```
preg_match('/visaObs((\d+));/s', $attribute, $match);
echo $match[0]; //undefined offset
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape `(` and `)`:

```
preg_match('/visaObs[(](\d+)[)];/s', $attribute, $match);
```

Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/1.php
<?
$attribute = "visaObs(31124228);";
preg_match('/visaObs[(](\d+)[)];/s', $attribute, $match);
print $match[1];
?>
$ php /tmp/1.php
31124228
```

If `matches` is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show me how to make use of the result? `$match[0]` or `$match[1]` seems to be undefined.

Comment: @Johan: `$match[1]`. See my answer; I've updated it.

Comment: Sweet. Is `$match[1]` null in case of a non matching string?

Comment: @Johan: Yes. Also, you can check result of the preg_match with `if`

Answer (score 2):

You must escape literal parenthesis:

```
/visaObs\((\d+)\);/
```

The s modifier is not needed, and your result is in `$match[1]` since it is the first capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions, a parenthesis is a special character.  You should escape the parenthesis around the numbers

```
preg_match('/visaObs\((\d+)\);/s', $attribute, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find *only* the number by matching any amount of digits, and include what should surround it:

```
preg_match('/(?<=visaObs\()\d+(?=\))/', $attribute, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not forced to use regex or a preg_ function to scan this predictably formatted text.  `sscanf()` can even cast the substring as an integer as part of its extraction process. No need to escape parentheses and no array of matches.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JD7d8))

```
$str = 'visaObs(31124228);';
sscanf($str, 'visaObs(%d)', $integer);
var_export($integer);  // 31124228
```